# ionic lazy loading, routes not working, after leaving

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, routes

I have two modules orders and products.I have lazily loaded their routes, everything is working on the first run, problem is when I leave the current route(order), and go come back to it, its not working anymore, I have called this route on my "login.component", this seems to be the problem, cause if I call the product, its the product routes that is not working. The url changes but the component wont change, below are my setup.

Github Repo: https://github.com/markanthonybanong/routing

//app.component.html

```
<ion-app>
  <ion-menu contentId="menu-content" menuId="menu-content" side="start" type="overlay">
    <ion-header>
      <ion-toolbar color="primary">
        <ion-title>Start Menu</ion-title>
      </ion-toolbar>
    </ion-header>
    <ion-content>
      <ion-list>
        <ion-menu-toggle>
          <ion-item routerLink="/order">
            <ion-icon name="clipboard-outline" slot="start"></ion-icon>
            <ion-label>Order</ion-label>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-menu-toggle>
        <ion-menu-toggle>
          <ion-item routerLink="/product">
            <ion-icon name="terminal-outline" slot="start"></ion-icon>
            <ion-label>Product</ion-label>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-menu-toggle>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
  </ion-menu>
  <ion-router-outlet id="menu-content"></ion-router-outlet>
</ion-app>
```

//app-routing.module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { PreloadAllModules, RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('./login/login.module').then(m => m.LoginModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'order',
    loadChildren: () => import('./order/order.module').then(m => m.OrderModule),
  },
  {
    path: 'product',
    loadChildren: () => import('./product/product.module').then(m => m.ProductModule),
  },

];
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { preloadingStrategy: PreloadAllModules })
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

//login.component.ts

```
  import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.scss'],
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  public myForm: FormGroup;
  constructor(
    public formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private router: Router
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      username: [null, Validators.required],
      password: [null, Validators.required]
    }); 
  }

  onSignUp(): void {
    if(this.myForm.value.username === "admin" && this.myForm.value.password === "admin"){
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/order');
    }
  }

}
```

//order.component.html

```
  <ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-title>
        ORDER
      </ion-title>
      <ion-buttons slot="start">
        <ion-menu-button auto-hide="false" (click)="openMenu()"></ion-menu-button>
      </ion-buttons>
    </ion-toolbar>
    <ion-toolbar>
      <ion-segment (ionChange)="onSegmentChanged($event)" value="order-list">
        <ion-segment-button value="order-list">
          <ion-label>Order List</ion-label>
        </ion-segment-button>
        <ion-segment-button value="add-order">
          <ion-label>Add Order</ion-label>
        </ion-segment-button>
      </ion-segment>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>
  <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

//order-routing.module

```
   import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AddOrderComponent } from './add-order/add-order.component';
import { OrderListComponent } from './order-list/order-list.component';
import { OrderComponent } from './order/order.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: OrderComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'order-list', pathMatch: 'full'},
      { path: 'order-list', component: OrderListComponent},
      { path: 'add-order', component: AddOrderComponent},
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class OrderRoutingModule { }
```

//product.component.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>PRODUCT</ion-title>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-menu-button auto-hide="false"></ion-menu-button>
   </ion-buttons>
  </ion-toolbar>
   <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-segment value="product-list" (ionChange)="segmentChanged($event)">
      <ion-segment-button value="product-list">
        <ion-label>Product List</ion-label>
      </ion-segment-button>
      <ion-segment-button value="add-product">
        <ion-label>Add Product</ion-label>
      </ion-segment-button>
    </ion-segment>
   </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

//product-routing.module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AddProductComponent } from './add-product/add-product.component';
import { ProductListComponent } from './product-list/product-list.component';
import { ProductComponent } from './product/product.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ProductComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'product-list', pathMatch: 'full'},
      {path: 'product-list', component: ProductListComponent},
      {path: 'add-product', component: AddProductComponent},
    ]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class ProductRoutingModule { }
```

Can someone shed some light on me. At this point i dont know what to do. In my knowledge i have done everything correctly.

Comment: do you have router-outlet in  component: MenuComponent, since all the children aka products and order will be render inside the menuComponent

Comment: @Indraraj26 yes sirr i have

Comment: Is it possible for you share minimal reproduction via github or https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-angular-v5-vkgpzy

Comment: @Indraraj26 yes sir here it is, https://github.com/markanthonybanong/routing

Comment: Please check the answer

Answer (score 1):

Change `router-outlet` to `ion-router-outlet` that should be in ion-content of product.component.html and order.component.html

```
<ion-content>
    <ion-router-outlet></ion-router-outlet>
 </ion-content>
```

Link docs: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/router-outlet